# Dygraphs: One series with two y-axes

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

What I would like to do is plot a single series with two y-axes "locked" to the same data -- for instance, °F and °C temperatures (or feet and meters, etc.) that could be read off either axis, but only one set of points would be plotted.

Things I have tried:

1) Create two series, the second with the converted values, and plot on "on top" of the other (in this case, there's a constant conversion value of 1.51):

date,unit1,converted_unit2
2012-03-19,1.598333,3.108333
2012-03-20,1.542083,3.052083
2012-03-21,1.483333,2.993333

Generally works; however, Dygraphs dynamically scales both y-axes independently to be "pretty", and so the two series don't always plot directly on top of each other.

2) Set visibility of the second series to FALSE:

series: { 'converted_unit2': { axis: 'y2' } },
visibility: [true, false]

Doesn't work: Dygraphs defaults to scaling secondary y-axis for invisible series to 0-to-1.

3) OK, keep them both visible, but set the second series to transparent:

series: { 'converted_unit2': { axis: 'y2' } },
colors: ['#000080','rgba(0,0,0,0)']

This *almost* works -- however it has the side effect that the label for the second series in the dynamic legend is now transparent. And, since the axes are still being independently calculated to be "pretty", they are not exactly aligned -- the secondary y-axis is potentially a few percentage off the first y-axis.

(I also tried setting the second series visibility to FALSE and manually setting the second y-asix using the values obtained from yAxisRange(), which works well, but the second y-axis doesn't respond correctly to zooming the graph.)

Is there a way to easily create two y-axes for a single series which are "locked" together?

Thanks,
-bryan

Answer (score 0):

same problem here ;)

we used to add a second (dependent) axis by using a single data point in a second series (which allowed a second axis) and fixed axis ranges for both axes (the second range calculated from the first range). Second color was set to transparent, second label was hidden ... worked fine until we had to switch to dynamically scaled axis ...

> the second series in the dynamic legend is now transparent

hm, you can change this with css (as it's an inline style, you'll have to use !important to override it) or js (remove the inline style or change it).

Yes, an option for a second (dependent) axis would be great!

Jean

Answer (score 0):

Set the stroke width of the second series to 0:

```
series: {
    converted_unit2: {
        axis: 'y2',
        strokeWidth: 0
        },
    }
```

Comment: Good hack (also may have to set the pointSize and highlightCircleSize to 0). Also, setting the yRangePad manually prevents series alignment problems when one of the y-axes bumps up against the zero lower bound.